# File not found error while importing protos

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, envoyproxy

I'm trying to create Go gRPC-client code with [this proto](https://github.com/envoyproxy/nighthawk/blob/main/api/client/output.proto) from the Nighthawk project and I'm getting this error:

```
user@computer:~/Code/nighthawk$ protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative api/client/output.proto 
envoy/config/core/v3/base.proto: File not found.
envoy/config/metrics/v3/stats.proto: File not found.
envoy/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/cert.proto: File not found.
envoy/config/core/v3/extension.proto: File not found.
validate/validate.proto: File not found.
api/client/options.proto: Import "envoy/config/core/v3/base.proto" was not found or had errors.
api/client/options.proto: Import "envoy/config/metrics/v3/stats.proto" was not found or had errors.
api/client/options.proto: Import "envoy/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/cert.proto" was not found or had errors.
api/client/options.proto: Import "envoy/config/core/v3/extension.proto" was not found or had errors.
api/client/options.proto: Import "validate/validate.proto" was not found or had errors.
api/client/options.proto:16:3: "envoy.config.core.v3.RequestMethod" is not defined.
api/client/options.proto:17:12: "envoy.config.core.v3.HeaderValueOption" is not defined.
api/client/options.proto:186:5: "envoy.config.core.v3.TypedExtensionConfig" is not defined.
api/client/options.proto:190:3: "envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext" is not defined.
api/client/options.proto:253:3: "envoy.config.core.v3.TransportSocket" is not defined.
api/client/options.proto:259:12: "envoy.config.metrics.v3.StatsSink" is not defined.
api/client/output.proto: Import "envoy/config/core/v3/base.proto" was not found or had errors.
api/client/output.proto: Import "api/client/options.proto" was not found or had errors.
api/client/output.proto:57:3: "nighthawk.client.CommandLineOptions" is not defined.
api/client/output.proto:59:3: "envoy.config.core.v3.BuildVersion" is not defined.
```

I see that these protos are defined in Envoy's repository [here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/main/api/envoy).

How do I import these so that I can generate the client code?

What is the command for this? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should not be building your own `.pb.go` files from other people's `.proto` files.  Go will panic if multiple definitions of the same proto package are found in a single binary, so every `.proto` file published should ideally also provide `.pb.go` files in a central location.  If that isn't the case for nighthawk, then you can still build that yourself.  You'll need to download the Envoy dependencies and reference them via the `-I` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I was trying that. Nighthawk does not provide Go stubs. So I have to generate it from the protos manually.

So downloading all the protos that are dependent here and passing its path through the -I flag is the straightforward way to do this right?

I also see this tool: https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate
from Envoy. How does this fit in here? Should I be using it somewhere to create the Go stub?

Comment: Yes, the `-I` flag _should_ be straightforward & the right way to do it.  For `protoc-gen-validate`, I don't believe you need to worry about that.  It should be an extension that building dependent protos doesn't require.  You shouldn't build the envoy protos yourself; you should use the go-control-plane repo's versions instead.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check this out and see if it is working.